# Implementing file upload type in Java

Tags: java, file, batch-file, content-type, mime

I have restricted my file upload type to txt only using .

```
FormFile fileObj = null;
```

So, even if someone changes an exe file to txt file and tries to upload it I am able to filter that out with the help of
 `AutoDetectParser,ParseContext,metadata`.

Now I have a batch file which after converting into txt, is successfully getting uploaded.

The content type of this file is text/plain the same for txt.

Now,
How can I restrict this file from being uploaded? 
Does each type of file content has some signature on the basis of which we can distinguish the uploaded file?
Is it possible to restrict these java file, batch file after converting it into txt?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about Windows batch files. These do not have a header or other characteristic which would make them accurately distinguishable from "normal" text files. Batch files *are*, in fact, "normal" text files, i.e. they're usually plain ASCII files. In order to detect them, you could think of arbitrarily complex heuristics - with varying success rate - so, no, you can't detect them reliably.

You can't really "restrict" batch files either, well OK, maybe. You could prepend `GOTO :eof` to the file or prefix every line with `REM` or `::`, which would effectively deactivate anything in the batch file. Or do other tricks, maybe.

But I am not entirely sure, why you would want to do that. In a normal web application, uploaded files should simply be stored to restricted part of the file system and not be executable. If an attacker can potentially run an uploaded file of any kind on some part of your infrastructure, it seems like an architectural problem to begin with.

Comment: So, I suppose if this is the case for windows batch files, all files that have readable content will have the same signature such as .java,.jsp,.vbs etc.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh: If by "same signature" you mean "no signature", then basically, yes, but also not entirely. For example some files allow for encoding in Unicode, and *might* start with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). This is a signature, but it doesn't allow to discriminate, say, .java from .vbs

Comment: So, is it possible to harness this BOM based on which we can distinct the file types? If yes, how?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh: As I just told you in the last sentence - *No, you cannot*.